# Getting "Could not parse the language" exception while publishing

Tags: sitecore-client, multilingual

While publishing the content in sitecore, the following error occured.

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
```

While checking on logs, i found the error with following language

```
Could not parse the language 'ms-BD'. Note that a custom language name must be on the form: isoLanguageCode-isoRegionCode-customName.
```

But that language is not installed, and there are no language corresponding to that code.

UPDATE #1: Add some more log details:

```
 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
Nested Exception
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
at Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext.Dispose()
```

Comment: anything more in the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: Is the language defined under the `/sitecore/system/Languages` node?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are trying to use culture 'ms-BD' that is not present in .NET by default.
Check that you definitely need 'ms-BD' and it is not mistake or misprint.

You can check cultures registered in system by running this C# console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
        Console.WriteLine("List of cultures registered in system");
        foreach (CultureInfo cul in cinfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cul.DisplayName + "  " + cul.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I get next cultures:

- Malay  ms
- Malay (Brunei Darussalam) ms-BN
- Malay (Malaysia)  ms-MY
- Malay (Latin, Singapore)  ms-SG

But you are trying to use 'ms-BD'.  Malay (Bangladesh)?
If it is not misprint/mistake and you are intended to use 'ms-BD' then you need to [register your custom culture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder__ctor_System_String_System_Globalization_CultureAndRegionModifiers_):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string culture = "ms-BD";
        string name = "Malay Bangladesh";

        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ms");
        RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo("BD");

        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(culture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(cultureInfo);
        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(regionInfo);

        // Custom Changes
        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = name;
        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = name;

        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
    }
}
```

After running this console application on machine where exception was occurred you will get new custom culture that should fix exception.